# send post data in jsf

Tags: jsf, post, redirect

I just cannot figure this out, it looks really simple but I'm relatively new at jsf.

Here is the old stuff:
Plain old html form tag like this:

```
<form name="someForm" action="somewhere" method="post">
   <input name="param1"/>
   <input name="param2" />
</form
```

That is sending data by post to a location specified in the action attribute of the form.

The new stuff:

```
<h:form id="paymentForm">
<h:panelGroup> 
    <h:inputText id="param1" value="#{facesView.param1}" ></h:inputText>
    <h:inputText id="param1" value="#{facesView.param2}" ></h:inputText>
    <h:panelGroup>
    <h:commandLink>Submit</h:commandLink>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

This other new stuff doesn't work.

1.How do I specify to this h:form where to go(like setting action in old html) because I need it to go to a totally new url.

2.how to pass params with POST?

Any help is appreciated.
Milos

Comment: With "totally new URL", do you mean an URL outside your webapp context? If so, what exactly do you want to do? Do you want to submit directly to this URL, or to act for a proxy?

Comment: Yes, to a URL outside webapp context(another web application to be precise).
I want to submit to this URL and send data by post, like the old stuff I mentioned above, just that there is www.somewhere.com/some.jsp(some.action, some.faces, whatever) in the action attribute of form, didn't write it though.

Comment: Bozho already answered it. Sorry, no other nice jsfish ways. It's in fact also not needed, you're not interested in the data nor action.

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC!
I supposed so when I read your article "Communications in JSF" and figured that there is no nice jsf way, yet I decided to ask a question.
At least I have some solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to submit a form to a URL where it will be handled by you (or someone else) manually, then you can still use the "old stuff" with JSF and have the form submitted. That way you will lose the ability to bind the values of the inputs to properties of managed bean.

Otherwise you can't choose the URL to submit to and at the same time use the bindings - in order to get the JSF functionality you have to submit to the JSF servlet, which in turn to handle everything.

Comment: That's exactly what I did to make the thing work(and it's working).
But I don't like it because of losing the binding to managed bean and I'm searching for a diferrent solution(if it exists :)). Thanks.

Comment: Me too looking to bind managed bean property with hidden inputs (params) of submitted plain vanilla form (POST request in my case).